# Partition of mdadm raid0 array passed through to win10 20H2 via virto driver is suddenly lost. How can I figure out why?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, kvm-virtualization, mdadm, virtio

I have checked the logs. System has been working for a month then suddenly they could not see the drive on network. It is a linux file server with a virtual windows on top of it ... Virtual windows has the virtio drive of 12*10 TB Disks shared over network...

The error on windows is : you should format this disk.
The error on linux is : mount syscall cannot be ... ,structure needs cleaning.

When I peek to drive via gparted I only see an ext partition cannot see ntfs partition in md0
it should contain an ntfs partition createn in virtual windows.

Comment: Exactly what storage did you give to the VM? Show the configuration. And exactly what error did you receive on Linux? What you posted seems to have important bits missing, or perhaps it was translated from another language. Give the complete error message in the original language.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no sensible logs in either virtual win10 or /var/log/libvirt/qemu and similar. I figured out whenever virtual machine or host machine change state such as sleep, hybrid-sleep, hibernate, suspend. There is risk of data corruption with default virtio SCSI drive settings.

I have disabled these states on both host and guest and recovered the drive using chkdsk. Btw testdisk did not work at all. gdisk could not restore partition info from backup either. Everything seems fine